# How to keep re-launching a windows form from the main program until another window form exits the application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, winforms, windows

I have a C# windows program which has two forms that open consecutively from the main program thread via RunApplication. The execution flow is essentially:

- User runs Setup.exe, launches the main program thread (Setup.cs)
- Main Program launches Form A, which diplays a list view of config files available
- User chooses one, clicks next, Form A closes
- Main Program thread loads the chosen config file
- Main Program thread launches Form B

  ```
  Application.Run(new FormB { Size = new Size(530, 421) });
  ```
- Form B has numerous tabs that may or may not display, depending on the config file selected; user clicks Next / Back on this form to navigate between the tabs
- If user is at tab index 0 of Form B and the user clicks on the Back button, Form B should close and allow Form A to show again

The last point is where I am having some issues - I was hoping that when a user clicks on the back button on Form B and the tab index is `0`, I could set some public static variable to indicate that it is 'return' mode, and re-launch Form A in the main thread. However, I can't use a simple loop to say that while it's not ExitMode (and is ReturnMode), launch Form B, since it'll open/close an instance of Form B repeatedly. I guess I could set the loop condition to say if it's ReturnMode and Form B hasn't already been launhched, launch Form B - but it's seems like a bad to be checking repeatedly until Form B has been closed. (Would threading be needed here?)

I also thought maybe I could launch Form A within Form B instead - e.g., if selected tab index is 0, then btnBack_Click of Form B runs a function to launch Form A. Since I can't launch `Application.Run()` inside of another Application.(), I created an instance of Form A and tried `formA.Show()`. However, if I do that, Form B lingers in the background and I can't seem to close it without closing Form A as well.

```
FormA form_a = new FormA { Size = new Size(530, 421) };                

FormB install_screens_active = Application.OpenForms["FormB"];
FormA.Show();

if (install_screens_active != null)
{ 
    install_screens_active.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        do
        {
            var formA = new FormA();
            Application.Run(formA);
            var formB = new FormB(formA.SelectedConfigurationFile);
            Application.Run(formB);
        } while (!IsComplete);
    }

    public static IsComplete { get; set;}
}

public class FormB
{
    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            Program.IsComplete = true;
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.IsComplete = true;
        Close();
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Tabs.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            Program.IsComplete = false;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that gave me the same result as just have a while loop - instances of FormA launching and closing endlessly, rather than just giving me a single instance of FormA and keeping that open.

Comment: See the comment. Something must set `Program.IsComplete = true` at some point. That would terminate the loop.

Comment: Also, I'm confused. Your post says FormA should close, but your comment here says that you want to keep it open. Which is it?

Comment: But I'd want Program.IsComplete to be true only when the user exits via FormB. I guess I could temporarily set Program.IsComplete to true when there is an instance of FormA already active, but I was wondering in my question whether continuously checking that was a good idea.

A *single* instance of FormA should launch IF user has returned to the main from FormB ; it should then allow user to pick a different config file and then re-launch Form B. If user clicks the back button Form B again, the same thing should occur.

Comment: What's the trigger for the user exiting FormB? A button? Or the standard windows [X] button?

Comment: Either the standard windows [x] button or the Cancel button.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked; I think the trick was actually not instantiating the new Forms inside of Run(...). So doing: [--- var formA = new FormA(); Application.Run(formA);---] rather than [--- Application.Run(new Form A (...)].

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference to the main thread to form B. From there, if the user presses the back button on form B when the index is at 0, call a method on the referenced thread that will close form B and open form A.